# Add Windows.Data.Pdf dependency in C#

Tags: c#, pdfdocument

I need to use this .NET class for one project I am working in (It's my first C# Project, I normally work in C++) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.pdf.pdfdocument?view=winrt-20348

Unfortunately this namespace Windows.Data.Pdf is not available in my project and I can't find in the docu the dll name I have to link to, to be able to access the class. Does anybody knows which dll do I need?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which framework do you use? `Windows.Data.Pdf` is only for UWP Apps.

Comment: Have you tried to add Reference to WinRT? You can add a reference to System.Runtime and System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll. It's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5 on my system.

Comment: Oh, now I see why I can't find it. I am in .Net 4.8 Framework. No UWP...

Comment: This could be actually done by adding references to winmd and System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime and there is a nuget package to automate this (https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#vZiZ96PlZUqTduts.97). It did work perfectly for me, while developing on classic projects targeting net45 and net46. However, both manual and nuget package based approaches do not work for me anymore since moving to SDK style projects using net48. I do not know which of both changes causes the solution not to work anymore.

Comment: You may forget my response above; I had to reinstall my Windows 10 SDK to get the right winmd file (not the x kb sized file in the Facade folder. I found another post on that, sorry I cannot track it back). The system.runtime.windowsruntime can be installed from nuget to do async loading of StorageFile (```await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(PdfPath)```)